# Running a Django server application through MATLAB

Tags: python, django, matlab, django-views, system-integration

There is a 'Python Power Electronics' simulator built with a Django server application. The simulator runs on a local server when the '**python manage.py runserver**' command is executed in the Anaconda prompt (I have created my own environment for this project in Anaconda). Using this simulator, one can create and analyze power electronic circuits—an excellent tool.

I am attempting to integrate the aforementioned simulator with MATLAB. This involves starting the server, selecting a specific simulation, and then running the simulation on 'Python Power Electronics' through a MATLAB script.

My question is: Is it possible to start the Django server through a MATLAB script and choose a specific simulation from the Simulations folder on the server?

Note: I've examined the source code of the 'Python Power Electronics' tool, a Python web framework. I have a basic understanding of the 'Run simulation' view in the `views.py` file, which is responsible for executing specific simulations.

Now, my primary task is to start the Django server using MATLAB code before delving into the simulation execution.

Any suggestions or answers are welcome.

Comment: Can you host the Django server manually instead of trying to build an automation pipeline? This will help you understand your issue.

Comment: Now I am able to run the Django server using MATLAB script. So at first, I have added my Anaconda virtual environment and its respective libraries to the PATH environment variable. then executed following commands in MATLAB:

Comment: % activate conda virtual env                                                          
system('conda activate --path to the respective Conda env--');                           % add the path to the directory
cd('-- path to the manage.py executable is present--');
system('--path to the python executable file-- manage.py runserver');

Comment: Note: can verify whether Matlab identifies the correct conda or python path using this commands: system('where conda')                     system('where python')